# what are the last digits in javascript new Date() object

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset, iana

when I execute the following line in Node

```
 > let x = new Date()
 > x
```

i get something like

```
2020-06-04T21:51:08.059Z
```

what is .059Z and how would it translate to GMT timezone?

Comment: `059` are milliseconds while `Z` says that the time is UTC, for further reference on JavaScript Date, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 1):

"Z" is kind of a unique case for DateTimes. The literal "Z" is actually part of the ISO 8601 DateTime standard for UTC times.

```js
    let x = new Date();
    let gmtZone = x.toGMTString();
    console.log(gmtZone)
```